# How to Convert Select Coordinates from WGS84 to NAD27?

Tags: r

I have a set of coordinates that use different reference systems. The majority of my data points were made using NAD27, while 8 of them were made using WGS84 for reasons beyond me. Is there any way for me to convert the WGS84 data points to data points that use NAD27?

Here's a sample of my data. You can see here that data points 4-7 were made using the WGS84 reference system, but I want them to use NAD27.

```
''r
animal.ID<-c( "TM07", "TM07", "TM07", "TM07","TM07","TM07","TM07")
X<-c(489410, 489411, 489179, 489168, 489178, 489173, 489170)
Y<-c(3723423,3723373,3723233,3723412,3723404,3723406,3723410)
datum<-c("NAD 27", "NAD 27", "NAD 27", "WGS 84","WGS 84","WGS 84","WGS 84")
data<-data.frame(animal.ID,X,Y,datum)
''r
```

I attempted to use a solution from a similar stack overflow question, but my coordinates kept coming out the same.

```
''r
data %>%
filter(datum=="WGS 84") %>% 
st_as_sf(coords = c("X", "Y"), crs = 4326) %>%
st_transform(4267)%>%
st_coordinates() %>% 
as_tibble()
''r
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think those values are actually `4326`, since they would be lat-long data if they were, right? Looks like all your coords are in meters.

Comment: Without further context, it looks like all of your data are projected coordinates, not geographic. If you want transform the data that you believe are based on the WGS84 datum, (1) Find our what projected coordinate system is used for your data. (2) Now convert them from whatever projected coordinate system they're in to WGS84. (3) Then convert from WGS84 to NAD27. (4) Reproject the transformed data from NAD27 to whatever projected coordinate system was used.